# CloudFormation - Terraform integration via SSM

Tags: terraform, integration, serverless-framework, aws-ssm

Some parts of my AWS infrastructure like S3 buckets/CloudFront distributions are deployed with Terraform and some other parts like serverless stuff are done with Serverless framework which is producing CloudFormation templates under the hood.

Changes in Serverless/CloudFormation stacks produces changes in API Gateway endpoint URLs, and running `terraform plan` against S3/CloudFront shows the difference in `origin` CloudFront block.

```
   origin {
-    domain_name = "qwerty.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
+    domain_name = "asdfgh.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    origin_id   = "my-origin-id"
    origin_path = "/path"
```

My idea was to write SSM on CloudFormation/Serverless deploy and read it in Terraform to be in sync.

Reading from SSM in `serverless.yml` is pretty straightforward, but I was unable to find the way to update SSM when deploying CloudFormation Stack. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll probably need to do something custom. Can I ask why? Generally you'd have a known domain in route53 which you could share, or if you wanted other services to programmatically access a lambda function, you can simply import the ARN from CF.

Comment: @AaronStuyvenberg regarding reason why I want to do it - will edit the question to make it clear

Comment: Ah. Then `serverless-ssm-publish` is probably the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

I found `serverless-SSM-publish` plugin which is doing the job of writing/updating SSM

just need to add this to `serverless.yml`

```
plugins:
  - serverless-ssm-publish

custom:
  ssmPublish:
    enabled: true
    params:
      - path: /qa/service_name/apigateway_endpoint_url
        source: ServiceEndpoint
        description: API Gateway endpoint url
        secure: false
```